# How to get the current value of BehaviorSubject once?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to get the current value of a `BehaviorSubject` *without* subscribing to it because I need to make some changes afterwards, without the changes reflecting real-time because of a specific requirement. I'm using `getValue()`.

Sample `BehaviorSubject` value:

```
{
  ID_123: {
     logs: [ 
       {
         id: 1,
         record_id: 'ID_123',
         data: { complete: false }
         action: 'Modified',
         description: 'Modified filename',
       }
     ]
  }
}
```

Service class:

```
private logs$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
private logsDataStore = {};
logsData = this.logs$.asObservable();

...

getData(id) {
   if (this.logsDataStore[id] !== undefined) {
       return this.logs$.getValue();
   }
}
```

I call `getData()` from inside a component when a button is clicked to render the `logs` entries.

```
id = 'ID_123';

onClick() {
   this.logsData = Object.assign({}, this.service.getData([this.id])[this.id]);
}
```

Rendering each `logs` entry:

```
<div *ngFor="let log of logsData.logs" class="log">
   <a *ngIf="!log.data.complete" (click)="markComplete(log.record_id, log.id, log.data)">
     Mark Complete
   </a>
</div>
```

```
markComplete(recordId, id, data) {
   let dataClone = Object.assign({}, data);
   dataClone.complete = true;
   this.service.updateLog(recordId, id, dataClone);
}
```

Back to the Service class:

```
updateLog(recordId: string, id: string, newValues: object) {
    const selectedRecord = this.logsDataStore[recordId];
    if (selectedRecord !== undefined) {
      if (selectedRecord.logs && selectedRecord.logs[id]) {
        let selectedLogEntry = selectedRecord.logs[id];
        Object.keys(newValues).forEach(
          (logKey) => {
            selectedLogEntry[logKey] = newValues[logKey];
          }
        );
      }
    }

    // this.logs$.next(Object.assign({}, this.logsDataStore));
  }
```

**The problem**:

Somehow, the Mark Complete link disappears right away whenever you click on it, even if I didn't subscribe to the service and cloned the results from `getData()` before using them? As though the reference to the object from the `BehaviorSubject` was retained?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered something new.

When I used:

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.service.getData([this.id])[this.id]));
```

**It worked.**

Previously, I assumed `Object.assign()` and `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` worked the same way, but it turns out, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify())` is the one that creates a *deep copy* and does not give you a reference to the original object.